# swap integral to polar

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Trying to swap to polar and solve the following double integral, but I am not getting the same answer.

$
\displaystyle\int_{-3/4}^{3/4} \int_{-\sqrt{3/4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{3/4-x^2}} 1/2\left(3-4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) dy dx
$

Here is the conversion into polar:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{3/4} rrdrd\theta = 9\pi/32
$$
Not sure if this is correct?

The above are an intermediate step which may be incorrect.
The original problem tries to find the volume bounded between the following:

$cone: z = 2 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, top of hyperboloid: $z= \sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$

$cylinder:  (x-1)^2+y^2 = 1$, plane $z=0$, cone $z= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Are there three integral signs in the double integral?

Comment: should be two integrals - edited posting

Comment: How are you doing that conversion to polar coordinates?  I think I understand your limits, but what's happening with the integrand?

Comment: $$
\int_0^{2\pi} 1/2 \int_0^{3/4} 3r - 4r^2 dr d\theta 
$$

Comment: Something looks not right with the cartesian integral limits.

Comment: Hm. Maybe that is my issue....It is an intermediate step. I included the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

The region of integration in your Cartesian coordinate double integral does not correspond to the one in your polar coordinate double integral.  The latter—which I suspect is the one you actually want—is the disc, $\ r\le\frac{3}{4}\ $ in polar coordinates, or $\ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le\frac{3}{4}\ $ in Cartesian coordinates. However, if that *is* the region you want to integrate over, then the limits on your inner integral in Cartesian coordinates aren't correct.  They should be $\ -\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}-x^2}\ $ and $\ \sqrt{\frac{9}{16}-x^2}\ $.

Comment: Ok - I'm doing something wrong. Added the entire problem in the post.